# check box not display checked although it have value true on database?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-7.0

I work on `blazor app` with .net core 7. i face issue when retrieve the value of check box boolean IsActive .

on database is active is 1 but on blazor app check box display false

so How to solve this issue

my code as below :

my issue is check box display no checked although it exist on database as 1 (checked)

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                <EditForm Model="@sn" OnValidSubmit="submit">
                 
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight mb-3">
                        <div class="p-2 w-100 bd-highlight">
                         
                       
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                        <div class="input-group-text">
                                            <input type="checkbox" aria-label="IsActive" id="IsActive" @bind-value="@sn.IsActive" />
                                        </div>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="IsActive">IsActive?</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                       
                      
                        </div>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                </EditForm>
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    @code
    {
        private bool IsActive { get; set; }
        private ServerNames sn = new ServerNames();
    
        private void editClick()
        {
            if (IsActive == true)
            {
                sn.IsActive = true;
            }
            else
            {
                sn.IsActive = false;
            }
    
    
        }
       
       
    }
```

Comment: i make as you tell me but when change from input to inputcheckbox i get error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    UC.AppRepository.UI.Pages.Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync.AnonymousMethod__14_1() in _Host.cshtml

Comment: so how to solve error above

Comment: I posted an answer showing how to use both ways... Note the different binds and use of upper and lower case. Hrmm `_Host.cshtml` is razor page why are you using a form here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<EditForm ...` is a built-in component designed to be used with the corresponding components for example `<InputText...`. In your case `<InputCheckbox @bind-Value="@sn.IsActive"`. Value is a property of InputCheckbox

To bind to a `<input type="checkbox"` just use `@bind=`

```
<input type="checkbox" ... @bind="@sn.IsActive" />
```